# How to left-justify a section heading in moderncv?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, moderncv

I'm trying to left-justify a subsection heading in my moderncv-based CV.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}

% These two lines have no effect
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\raggedright\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\raggedright\subsectionfont

\subsection{Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent varius nisl iaculis pellentesque dignissim. Aliquam fringilla accumsan mauris et aliquam.}

\end{document}
```

Including `titlesec` leads to the following error (it is repated twice for `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`)

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \subsubsection
l.1275 \ttl@extract\subsubsection
\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
```

Adding `\raggedright` at the beginning of the `\subsection` command causes errors [(logfile)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/848dc8b46319e53c97cd).

```
\subsection{\raggedright Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent varius nisl iaculis pellentesque dignissim. Aliquam fringilla accumsan mauris et aliquam.}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility; the `\RRsubsection` command was defined in a similar fashion to the standard `\subsection`, but will typeset the title ragged right:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\RRsubsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{} & \raggedright{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{0.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent varius nisl iaculis pellentesque dignissim. Aliquam fringilla accumsan mauris et aliquam.}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} 
\RRsubsection{Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent varius nisl iaculis pellentesque dignissim. Aliquam fringilla accumsan mauris et aliquam.}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have expressed myself unclearly. I don't want to change where the heading starts on the left side, I want to disable justification on the right one (i.e. the effect of `\raggedright`.

Comment: @Erik Ah. And what do you want to replace `\raggedright` with?

Comment: I don't want to replace `\raggedright` by anything; I'm looking for a way to apply it to a heading.

Comment: @Erik Please see my updated answer.